# silverstripe - restore deleted pages

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

is there a way to restore deleted pages in silverstripe? I do not find such an option in the silverstripe backend. though you can find the deleted pages still in the database in the table SiteTree_versions.
thx,
florian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SilverStripe 2.4 - under Page Tree there is a "Show" field with a dropdown. Under that dropdown there is an option "All pages, including deleted".

For SilverStripe 3.0 - open the Filter panel under the Pages section. Change the Pages option to "All pages, including deleted".

Selecting this option in either version of the CMS shows all pages including deleted ones. You can then restore a page by selecting it and clicking "Restore".

Comment: huh - i never looked at this dropdown. thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 0):

working for me in 2.4:

1. find the latest version of the page in the SiteTree_versions table. find the version id in field 'Version'
2. go to `/admin/getversion/[page id]/[version id]`
3. click 'restore'

Answer (score 0):

For me "All pages, including deleted" was broken ( could not figure out why ) so I tried the below:

/admin/pages/edit/show/[Page ID]

and clicked restore.